# EditText space between image and text

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have defined the `EditText` like below

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/searchText"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/grey"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/searchsmall"
    android:drawablePadding="15dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
     />
```

The output.

[image]

I have set the `android:drawablePadding` but text is not moving to the right.

I want he results like below.

[image]

How can I do it ?

Thanks

Comment: Try to change `android:drawableStart` to `android:drawableLeft`

Comment: Thanks, I have tried but no results. I think I have to user separate imageview for this.

Comment: I tried your code and its working in my case

Comment: make 15dp to 50dp you will see the difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use below code

```
 android:drawablePadding="5dp"
```